# Checking for HTML5 data attribute with no value

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element that has an HTML5 `data` attribute with no value but just the key like this:

```
<div id="1" data-foo>Foo</div>
```

If I use `dataset` like this:

```
getElementById("1").dataset.foo
```

then, this will return a null value, and I cannot distinguish whether the element has `data-foo` attribute or not. Is there are way to check if the element has a `data-foo` attribute regardless of whether it has a specified value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this by checking if the element contains the attribute using the `hasAttribute` method:

```
document.getElementById('1').hasAttribute('data-foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

If the element does not feature the `data-foo` attribute, a call to `dataset.foo` will return `undefined`, rather than `null` (or an empty string in the case of an empty attribute).

You should check the actual value, as follows:

```
var fooVal = document.getElementById('div1').dataset.foo;

// data-foo is not present at all:
if( fooVal === undefined )
{

} 

// data-foo is present but empty
if( fooVal === '' )
{

}
```

Of course, you could cast the logic to a simple boolean:

```
var hasFoo = ( document.getElementById('div1').dataset.foo !== undefined );
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1cno79pb/1/)

Comment: Not correct. If data-foo is present, fooVal is the empty string, not null.

Comment: @Alohci You are right. So the first form is wrong but the second form is correct, I guess.

Comment: Is there any possibility of an explicitly set value being `undefined`?

Comment: @sawa - not via the markup attribute, no. Some pedants however will argue that you shouldn't do a `=== undefined` test because it's theoretically possible in JavaScript for `undefined` to be defined!, and that therefore your test should be `=== void 0` because `void 0` always evaluates to undefined. I'm not one of them.

Comment: @Alohci I don't believe the ability to define the `undefined` value has been a thing for many years.. So everyone should be safe to use it now.